# Auto-complete AWK variable

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to auto-complete the name of a variable (array), in this way:

```
array$1[something]++
```

I'm trying to obtain this:

```
array1[something]++
```

or

```
array53[something]++
```

In C, I remember I couldn't do that.. but in AWK I don't know, because if I do:

```
array'$1'[something]++
```

it auto-completes the name:

```
arraySCRIPTPARAMETER[something]++
```

Any ideas? Am I wrong?

Comment: why not use a 2-dimentional array instead? like `myArray[num,something]` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rethink your code, possibly using a 2D array.

Your snippet:

```
array'$1'[something]++
```

only works 'by accident' and 'by connivance with the shell'.  What must be happening is that you have a script that looks a little like this (there'd be more to the whole script, but this is the bit that matters pro tem):

```
awk '/something/ { array'$1'[something]++ }'
```

The shell removes the single quotes (`awk` doesn't see them) and also replaces the `$1` with the first argument to the shell script, thus creating what `awk` sees as:

```
/something/ { arrayPARAM1[something]++ }
```

Notice that the name is fixed for the duration of the `awk` script; the `$1` is not the first field of the current line of input.

So, that's what is actually happening.  Without more of your code (or the purpose of your code) available, it isn't possible to state exactly what you should do instead, but as I said up front, a 2D array is distinct possibility for a better solution to what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this:

```
array$1[something]++
```

It would be better if you do this instead:

```
array[$1, something]++
```

You can also store your indices to another variable like:

```
indices[i++]=$1
```

Then later do

```
for (i = 0; i in indices; ++i) {
    k = indices[i]
    printf "something of %s: %s\n", k, array[k, something]
}
```